# How to move along in a json file. #React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to I can move along and back in a json file, see this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7BqT.png (Sorry, I can´t post img :/) I want that when the arrows below can move along in the json file. It´s like

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "word": "Silla",
      "engword": "Chair",
      "deuword": "Stuhl"
 },
{
      "id": 2,
      "word": "Algo",
      "engword": "Something",
      "deuword": "Etwas"
 },
```

And this is how i send my words to each component.

```
 function App() {
   return (
     <div>
       <div id="container">
         <div id="spanish">
           <Spanish word={words.words[0].word} />
         </div>
         <div id="app">
           <div id="english">
             <English word={words.words[0].engword} />
           </div>
           <div id="deutsch">
             <Deutsch word={words.words[0].deuword} />
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div id="controls">
         <Previous />
         <Next />
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
```

I want to make that when I click the next arrow i send to English component something like that

```
<English word={words.words[actualword+1].engword} />
```

Comment: If the words are inside words array, you can use map like this `words.map(word=>{ your logic here})`.

Comment: It cant work because I don´t want to render all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the App from functional Componenet to class component

create initial state with step

```
this.state = { step: 0 }
```

pass the set state function to next and prev components

```
 <Previous onClick={() => setState({ step: step - 1 })} />

 <Next onClick={() => setState({ step: step + 1 })} />
```

should look somthing like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { step: 0 }
  }
  render () {
    const { step } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div id='container'>
          <div id='spanish'>
            <Spanish word={words.words[step].word} />
          </div>
          <div id='app'>
            <div id='english'>
              <English word={words.words[step].engword} />
            </div>
            <div id='deutsch'>
              <Deutsch word={words.words[step].deuword} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id='controls'>
          <Previous onClick={() => setState({ step: step - 1 })} />
          <Next onClick={() => setState({ step: step + 1 })} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**add default min and max values for step
and check from step<0 and array boundaries**

Comment: Thanks you very much bro, I use your code as a reference and it works <3!

Answer (score 0):

make it a higher order component where you have state

```
<Spanish word={this.state.word} />
```

and change the state with the arrow onClick